# Solving $\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}}} = 2^{512}$.

Tags: exponentiation

I can't solve this question I have tried but I can't find any other websites that help. Thanks

$$\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}}} = 2^{512}$$

This is not infinite exponent just 2 times

Comment: Can you please put parentheses around the terms which belong together and write it in MathJax.

Comment: @Unknown Here is a handy tutorial for writing equations in mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: One solution is to numerically solve $x\log_2\left(x\right)+\log_2\left(\log_2\left(x\right)\right)=9$, although I don't think this is particularly elegant.

Comment: Compare with $4^{4^4}$ .

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: ok i understand I will post better questions

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  First define $y=\sqrt x$ to clean things up.  Then if you are in the integers note that $y$ must be a power of $2$ so let $y=2^z$.  Plug that in and use the laws of exponents.  Taking the $\log_2$ of the equation will also clean things up a bit.

If you are in the reals you have $$y^{y^y}=2^{512}\\
y^y\log_2y=512\\y\log_2 y +\log_2(\log_2 y)=9$$
and we can do fixed point iteration with $$y=\frac {9-\log_2(\log_2 y)}{\log_2 y}$$
I find $y=4$ is a solution, so $x=16$

Comment: Why must $y$ be a power of $2$? If we were solving $y^y=2^6$ for example, we'd have $y\approx3.4$, which isn't a power of $2$.

Comment: Of course, we can see that $\sqrt{x}$ *is* a power of $2$ but I'm not sure how you've justified it.

Comment: I was assuming you were working in the integers. If you are in the real you are right. Then just take the $\log_2$ of the $y$ stack twice and do a numeric solution.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems like there wouldn't be a closed-form for non-integer solutions.